# How to refresh QgsMapcanvas?

Tags: python, qgis

I am using Qgis 1.7 and I want to refresh the mapcanvas
so I am using refresh() function of QgsMapcanvas class 
and Nothing is happening to the Map Canvas.
I am using Python for customizing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use

```
self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

in Time Manager plugin and it works. You can check the source on Github.

Answer (score 5):

In QGis 2.16, with refresh() still nothing is happening. 
I use this command to refresh all layers:

```
self.iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```

Comment: To expand on this `.refresh()` "Repaints the canvas map" whereas `.refreshAllLayers()` will "Reload all layers, clear the cache and refresh the canvas" - from the [docs](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.4/gui/QgsMapCanvas.html?highlight=refreshalllayers#qgis.gui.QgsMapCanvas.refresh)